# Trying to remember sci-fi book about binary star system

Tags: story-identification, novel, espionage

I have been trying to recall a book I originally read in French that I would love to read again. 
 This is what I remember from the book:

1. It was set on a planet that had a binary (I think) star system where the inhabitants on the planet were of Asian decent and had to wear special protection depending upon which sun was facing the planet.
2. The protagonist was sent there to spy on something, but I cannot remember what that was. He had to undergo treatments to make him look Asian/Chinese since he was white.
3. There was an element of romance to the novel.
4. I think the title, in French, either had the word Tiger or Dragon in it.

   I know this isn’t a lot to go on and I am not sure of what the title would be in English.

   I’m hoping maybe someone out there can help me identify this book so I can find it and read it again.

Edit:

The book was originally in French because I remember seeing an English translation of it in a used book sale. Still kicking myself that I didn’t buy that book that day.

I remember reading it around 2005-2006, so I hope this helps.

I think the book is a standalone and not a part of a series.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Does any of [these titles](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_language&OPERATOR_1=exact&TERM_1=French&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&OPERATOR_2=exact&TERM_2=NOVEL&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&USE_3=title_title&OPERATOR_3=contains&TERM_3=tigre&ORDERBY=title_copyright&START=0&TYPE=Title) ring a bell?

Comment: Or any of [these](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_language&OPERATOR_1=exact&TERM_1=French&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&OPERATOR_2=exact&TERM_2=NOVEL&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&USE_3=title_title&OPERATOR_3=contains&TERM_3=dragon&ORDERBY=title_copyright&START=0&TYPE=Title)?

Comment: So far none of those titles unfortunately aren’t ringing a bell. I did look up some of those that weren’t English translations of books just to be for sure. I do appreciate all of the help though since it is helping me to narrow the field down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after a random google search on Quebecois authors and books with Dragon in this title (since I bought the book while I was in Montreal), I finally found the book by recognizing the cover. It seems like I got at least the Dragon part right of the title.

The book is *La taupe et le dragon* by Joël Champetier. Here is a Goodreads link to it: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6467410-la-taupe-et-le-dragon

I highly recommend this book because it was an awesome combination of a spy novel and scifi.

I do want to thank everyone for their efforts and now giving me more books to read.

Merci beaucoup!!

Answer (score 2):

(Definitely not a match, but I'll leave this here so that's noted - just saw the OP's edit that their book was originally published in French, and these were originally published in English).

While it's far from a perfect match, the first thing I thought of was Jack L Chalker's [Four Lords of the Diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Lords_of_the_Diamond) series.

As with every Chalker work I've ever read, body transformation is involved. A man is needed to act as an agent on the four planets in the Warden Diamond, a system used as a prison. He's investigating crimes that have been traced back to this prison system (matching the "spy" aspect mentioned). Unfortunately, once in that system, one can't leave it. To solve this problem, the agent's consciousness is written over the minds of four convicts headed for the system. On some of the planets, additional body transformations happen. On Cerberus, people's consciousness' can swap bodies; on Charon, one can use the equivalent of magic to completely transform their bodies.

The four books in the series are:

- *Lilith: A Snake in the Grass*
- *Cerberus: A Wolf in the Fold*
- *Charon: A Dragon at the Gate*
- *Medusa: A Tiger by the Tail*

Note the last two books have "Tiger" and "Dragon" in the title. And, in most of the books, the agent did form romantic relationships.

Where it doesn't match up: I don't believe the Warden Diamond system had a binary star, and the four planets in the system were not segregated on racial lines.

Also, *Medusa* should have stood out, as the story of that book's primary protagonist only consumes about 2/3 of the book, with the last 1/3 devoted to wrapping up the framing story of the investigation the agent was sent to perform. It wouldn't have been the best place to start reading.

Still, there seemed to be enough matching elements to bring it up.